# BDD Specflow code navigation in Xamarin Studio

Tags: xamarin, bdd, specflow

As a project requirement, I m using Xamarin Studio to execute iOS automation Test cases. I need help on any shortcut available for Xamarin Studio to navigate to the StepDefinition file from the feature file and vice versa. Similar functionality exists for Visual Studio, by using F12 key.

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0):

I tried Specflow with the help of an addin for Xamarin Studio : [https://github.com/mikeyjones/SpecFlow](https://github.com/mikeyjones/SpecFlow#specflow).

There is a GitHub Repository discussing about the sample : https://github.com/RobGibbens/BddWithXamarinUITest

Refer this Article : http://arteksoftware.com/bdd-tests-with-xamarin-uitest-and-specflow/